# How to send data to a running activity from Broadcast Receiver,

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am able to receive C2DM message fine but I want to send the data to a running activity, i.e when the activity is running, if the receiver receives C2DM message it is to send the data to the running activity. The code of receiver is (no bugs in the code):

```
public class C2dmreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) 
        {
            final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("key1");   
            Log.d("C2DM", "message = " + payload );
       }
     }}
```

I have tried like this inside the activity in an attempt to register the receiver in the activity so that the receiver can send data and the running activity can receive the data :-

```
C2dmreceiver c2dmr = new C2dmreceiver();
Registration.this.registerReceiver(c2dmr, new IntentFilter());
```

I don't know what to put inside the IntentFilter(), also what else I have to put in the code of the activity and the code of the receiver so that while the activity is running and some C2DM message comes the receiver can send the data to the running activity.

So, please tell me the code that is to put in the activity and in the receiver and may also be in the manifest so that the data from the receiver could be send to running activity.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all it's not the best idea to subscribe c2dm receiver in activity. Do it in manifest. For passing data to activity you can create static string field in Activity and set you String there.

You can do something like this:

in `Activity`

```
public static YourActivity mThis = null;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mThis = this;
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mThis = null;
}
```

In your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
if (YourActivity.mThis != null) {
    ((TextView)YourActivity.mThis.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("received c2dm");
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: I need my activity get the C2DM data from the receiver and also be notified of the arrival of the data, how that can be done? I just want to know how activity be register to some particular broadcast receiver and get updates as they are received by the receiver.

Comment: You should not register C2DMReceiver in Activity - because messages can come when activity is not started - you have to workout this message. For passing data you can use static fields or singleton.

Comment: Please can you give an example implementation.

Comment: hmm i don't know if this is a good practice, but a really nice idea, and it's working

Comment: can u plz help me in this : ((TextView)YourActivity.mThis.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("received c2dm"); ..i didn't understand this and by copy n paste it shows error..